# QtCreator 4.4.1 MINGW and Qt 5.9.1 Can not debug Qt sources

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator

I recently am struggling by trying to debug Qt sources with my MINGW,QtCreator,Qt installation.
I did create a sample app, deployed it with the windeployqt tool and let it execute but when I am trying to debug, let s say step into one of the fancy Qt classes and methods I did obtain assembly code. I am plagued by assemply code also when trying to step over the

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

I did build Qt from sources so the sources should not be a problem, I did not move the sources nor removed them.
When I used the objdump tool against qt libraries (debug version) to understand where the sources had to be I discovered that the libs were pointing to the correct source location.
I did also tried to play with the qtcreator qt source mappings but I did lost only a whole day by trying to understand what the heck those mappings do expect and either this try did not get me nothing.
In short, I have qt sources where they should be but gdb is for some reason not getting it.
This is my CMakelists.txt make file which one am importing in QtCreator:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project(sampleapp2)

#set(DEPS -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32)
set(QT_DEPS "")

find_package(Qt5Widgets)
if(Qt5Widgets_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    set(QT_DEPS ${QT_DEPS} ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES})
endif()

find_package(Qt5Core)
if(Qt5Core_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    set(QT_DEPS ${QT_DEPS} ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES})
endif()

find_package(Qt5Gui)
if(Qt5Gui_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    set(QT_DEPS ${QT_DEPS} ${Qt5Gui_LIBRARIES})
endif()

#print qt deps (if any has been found), if not do exit
if(QT_DEPS)
    message(STATUS "Qt dependencies are: " ${QT_DEPS})
else()
    message(STATUS "Qt dependencies not found, exiting...")
    exit()
endif()

#set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CXXFLAGS -g)
set(QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -g)

set(GUI_TYPE WIN32)
set(LIB_SOURCES maindialog.cpp)
set(EXE_SOURCES main.cpp)
set(UI_LIB sampleapp2ui)

QT5_WRAP_CPP(sampleapp2ui_hdr_moc maindialog.h)
QT5_WRAP_UI(sampleapp2ui_form_hdr maindialog.ui)

set(LIB_SOURCES ${LIB_SOURCES} ${sampleapp2ui_hdr_moc} ${sampleapp2ui_form_hdr})

add_library(${UI_LIB} SHARED  ${LIB_SOURCES})
#qt5_use_modules(${UI_LIB} Core Gui Widgets)
target_link_libraries(${UI_LIB} ${QT_DEPS})

add_executable(sampleapp2 ${GUI_TYPE} ${EXE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(sampleapp2 ${UI_LIB} ${QT_DEPS})
#target_link_libraries(sampleapp2 ${UI_LIB})
#qt5_use_modules(sampleapp2 Core Gui Widgets)
```

Another wired thing is that I completely can not jump in the maindialog.cpp definitions which is something I should be able to - the maindialog.cpp is not part of any qt library - it is my own main dialog wrapped around the qt resources that I am using to specialize it.

Thank you in advice!

Comment: Have created a QtCreator bug as this stuff is very annoying and it seems that there are many people around that are experiencing this issue. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-19093

Comment: RUNNING GDB FROM THE COMMAND LINE I AM ABLE TO DIG INSIDE THE QT SOURCES WITHOUT ANY ISSUE SO IT IS CLEAR THAT THIS IS A NASTY EMBEDDED QTCREATOR FEATURE THAT AT FIRST IS NOT WORKING AND AT SECOND IT CAN NOT BE DISABLED.

Comment: Fixed by building QtCreator from sources.

Comment: Following the comment by Tasuku Suzuki from https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-19093, copying `Qt\X.Y.Z\mingwX_Y\lib\*.debug` into `Qt\X.Y.Z\mingwX_Y\bin\ ` is a workaround (it's few GB, I didn't test if it's okay to move it, instead of copying). Worked for me on Qt 5.15.2 & mingw81_64.